# Animator Bool or Trigger?

Tags: unity, animation

[image]
I'm wondering about these two things. for what is better to use Bool rather than Trigger ? If i'm going to use Trigger, I should use it for what ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Bool type is appropriate for representing a state that holds true over a period of time e.g. carrying an item or entering sneak mode .

The Trigger type is appropriate for representing an action that will occur for a short period e.g. recoil from a gun firing or stumbling after a collision. Usually after this action is complete the animation returns back to a normal or default state.

From a mechanical perspective a value passed to [Animator.SetBool()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetBool.html) will persist within the animation system until changed by a subsequent call to this method.  Conversely if a true value is passed to [Animator.SetTrigger()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html) the value within the animation system will be automatically reset to false after it has been used in a state transition.